# path to desktop folder on mac

Tags: python

is there a path that works with python's OS module to access the desktop folder on mac? something like

```
os.chdir('iCloud Drive/Desktop')
```

ive looked at the path through finder, but all it says is that the desktop folder is found in the icloud drive, but i tried using that path and it didn't work. ive also tried searching for alternatives, but nothing came up

[the given path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/311ix.png)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`~/Desktop` normally is the path you want. Note: I tested in a GitHub Actions macOS runner, as I don't have a macOS myself.

```bash
$ python -c "import os; path = os.path.expanduser('~/Desktop'); print(os.path.exists(path))"
True
```

Please notice that not using `os.path.expanduser` makes `~` be read as literal, hence failing to find the directory:

```bash
$ python -c "import os; print(os.path.exists('~/Desktop'))"
False
```

EDIT: Complementing, you can easily change or see contents. For instance, create a directory:

```bash
$ python -c "import os; newpath = os.path.expanduser('~/Desktop/newdir'); os.makedirs(newpath); print(os.path.exists(newpath))"
True
```